# Does anyone know a good way to play Forbidden Island with one player

Tags: forbidden-island

Noone wants to play board games with me and I was wondering if you would need to change the rules at all to play with one player in Forbidden Island

Comment: Most Forbidden Island games I've played with others feel like a one-player game already...

Answer (score 8):

In Forbidden Island, the players have no secrets from each other. There is also no real-time component to the game or other physical limitation that benefit from multiple real players. As such, you can simply play alone by playing with more than one character. Each character has its own hand and plays in turn as if they were played by different people.

Comment: I would add that this is true of most, if not all cooperative board games.

Comment: No, only those that meet the criteria that I mentioned. For example, Damage Report and Escape can't be played alone without adjustment.

Comment: @Andrew Certainly not all, a number of co-ops have secret information that the players are not allowed to reveal to each other (Hanabi being a classic example).